# Capitalize issue with bracket text/content

Tags: css

I have `HTML` page where I have many labels added with (s) like Cat(s), Dog(s), Page(s), etc and I have `CSS` property for them as

```html
 <html>
        <head>
            <style>
         label{
          text-transform: capitalize;
         }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label>Cat(s) : 5</label>
            <label>Dog(s) : 4</label>
        </body>
    </html>
```

it is working fine on most of the browsers but some like chrome are showing (s) as capital (S), but it should not be.

Check https://codepen.io/vikramtalkin/pen/ZdeQmW  on chrome and firefox, on firefox it shows properly but on chrome it shows (S)

Please suggest possible solutions.

Comment: show that `html` code with `label` tags

Comment: Why it shouldn't be like that? Once you capitalize the text, then it should be all capitalized. The `shouldn't` is different from the `I want it like that`. Also, could you provide your actual `HTML` / `CSS` ?

Comment: Update the question with codepen link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest that comes to mind, using CSS and with the existing markup, is to use `:first-letter`.

With `:first-letter` it will only capitalize the first letter in `label`'s, and leave the `s` in `(s)` be.

*Do note, the `label` need to be displayed `block` or `inline-block`*

Stack snippet

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
label::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<label>Cat(s) : 5</label>
<label>Dog(s) : 4</label>

<label>cow(s) : 5</label>
<label>horse(s) : 4</label>
```

---

**Edit**

Based on a comment, where there might be more than just one word.

In a sentence like "i have dog(s)" one can't capitalized arbitrary words, e.g. "I" and "Dog" but not "have". For that you need a script.

If to capitalize all words, you can't use `:first-letter`, and if so, you need to wrap the text that should be capitalized, in e.g. a `<span>`, to avoid the "s" in "(s)" to be affected (how Chrome does).

And note, it works the same way in Opera and Edge, as it does in Chrome, and likely in Safari as well, given it also use WebKit, so I guess it is only in FireFox the "(s)" isn't affected.

Comment: Can you add "I have Dog(s)" in answer and check if it works ?

Comment: @VikramSingh First off, you don't have that in your question. Second, you can't capitalized arbitrary words, e.g. "I" and "Dog" but not "have". For that you need a script. If to capitalize all words, you can't use `:first-letter`, and if so, you need to wrap the text that should be capitalized, in e.g. a `span`, to avoid the `s` in `(s)` to be affected (how Chrome does).

Comment: @VikramSingh And note, it works the same way in Opera and Edge, as it does in Chrome, so I guess it is only in FF it works how you appear to want (haven't tried Safari, but since it also use WebKit I guess it does how Chrome does).

Comment: @VikramSingh I updated my answer with the same I wrote in my comments